# Drawable images in List not displaying on Android Studio. (Kotlin)

Tags: android, list, kotlin

**Upadted MainFragment.kt**

```
private val FoodList = listOf(
    Food(R.drawable.burget,"Biriyani", 100),
    Food(R.drawable.coke,"Fried Rice", 80),
    Food(R.drawable.eggbiriyani,"Idli", 30),
    Food(R.drawable.burget,"Masala Dosa", 40),
    Food(R.drawable.icecream,"Ice Cream", 40),
    Food(R.drawable.burget,"Apple Juice", 50),
    Food(R.drawable.burget,"Orange Juice", 50),
    Food(R.drawable.burget,"Mango Juice", 50)
)
```

**Upadted data class Food**

```
data class Food(val image: Int, val name: String, val price: Int)
```

**Updated FoodViewHolder.kt**

```
class FoodViewHolder (inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)) {
    private var FoodName: TextView? = null
    private var FoodPrice: TextView? = null


    init {
        FoodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name)
        FoodPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_price)
    }

    fun bind(food: Food) {
        FoodName?.text = food.name
        FoodPrice?.text = food.price.toString()
    }
}
```

**Updated FoodAdapter.kt**

This is my adapter code but i dont know where to place the changes.
I use `bind` in the `FoodViewHolder` to access the `data class Food` but I am unable to find the right code to access an image.

```
class FoodAdapter(private val list: List<Food>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return FoodViewHolder(inflater, parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodViewHolder, position: Int) {
        setImageResources(list[position].image)
        val food: Food = list[position]
        holder.bind(food)
    }

    private fun setImageResources(image: Int): Int {
        return R.id.food_image
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

}
```

Please help me out using the kotlin code. The images are not showing the ones that i had mentioned as per the drawable in the main fragment.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

You can not set image resource as a string.

**Create a list like this:**

```
private val FoodList = listOf(
        Food(R.drawable.burget,"Biriyani", 100),
        Food(R.drawable.coke,"Fried Rice", 80),
        Food(R.drawable.eggbiriyani,"Idli", 30),
        Food(R.drawable.burget,"Masala Dosa", 40),
        Food(R.drawable.icecream,"Ice Cream", 40),
        Food(R.drawable.burget,"Apple Juice", 50),
        Food(R.drawable.burget,"Orange Juice", 50),
        Food(R.drawable.burget,"Mango Juice", 50)
    )
```

**Your data model should look like this**

```
data class Food(val image: Int, val name: String, val price: Int)
```

**Set image in an adapter like this**

```
 FoodImage.setImageResources(food.image)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Food(R.drawable.burget,"Biriyani", 100)`-> First Parameter Should be **`Int`** instead of <s>String</s>.

**Your Model class will be**

```
data class Food(val image: Int, val name: String, val price: Int)
```

Then Adapter section

```
FoodImage.setImageResources(food.image) //setImageResources(list[position].image)
```

> public void setImageResource (int resId) ->
>     Use a resource id to set the content of the ImageView.

Comment: I didn't undestand the change that I have to make in the Adapter section. Hence I have added the Adapter, so please look into it. Wll be grateful if you would help me out.

Comment: `setImageResources(list[position].image)`

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in your bind function.

```
FoodImage.setImageResources(food.image)
```

Comment: It says "setImageResouces" as 'unresolved Reference'. What do i do next?

Comment: just Read the method implementation it will give you a proper guide.